# Hiding bookmark icon in the gutter

Tags: intellij-idea, bookmarks

I am using Intellij idea Ultimate 2017.2 edition.Does anybody know way to just hide specific icons
in the gutter instead of hiding the entire gutter itself.Specifiacally , How do i hide the
bookmark icon in the gutter.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IntelliJ IDEA doesn't have an option to hide bookmark icons from the gutter bar at the moment. Feature request is [welcome](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/newIssue?project=IDEA).